# Aws-CDK Modifying the Security Group generated by CfnMicrosoftAD

Tags: aws-cdk

CfnMicrosoftAD creates a security group - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_getting_started_what_gets_created.html I need to allow outbound UDP access on port 1812 to a server in the same VLAN (ie. add an outbound custom rule to the security group), but cannot work out how to do this using cdk.  How can I reference the security group created?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an AwsCustomResource to make an api call to describeDirectories and pull out the securityGroupId from the vpcsettings and use it with a call to SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId to then modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example in Typescript demonstrating how to use the AWS Custom Resource to make an API call to fetch the security group ID. As mentioned by Max, you can either use the describeDirectories API call or the [describeSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeSecurityGroups-property) API call.

The default AD security group is named on the following fixed pattern: `<active-directory-id>_controllers`. So, we are filtering out the security group based on its name. Once we have the security group ID, we can then import it in our stack as described below:

```js
// Import the AD's ID
const directoryId = Fn.importValue('DirectoryStack-ActiveDirectoryID');

// Fetch the Active Directory's security group ID by making an AWS API call
 const customResource = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'ADSecurityGroupId-CustomResource', {
   onUpdate: {
     // Will also be called for a CREATE event
     service: 'EC2',
     action: 'describeSecurityGroups',
     parameters: {
       Filters: [
         {
           Name: 'group-name',
           Values: [`${directoryId}_controllers`], // The Security Group's name is passed to fetch the Security Group's ID
         },
       ],
     },
     outputPaths: ['SecurityGroups.0.GroupId'],
     physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
     // Update physical ID to always fetch the latest version
   },
   policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
     resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE,
   }),
});

const securityGroupId = customResource.getResponseField('SecurityGroups.0.GroupId');
// Import AD's security group
const importedADSecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(
  this,
  'importedADSecurityGroup',
  securityGroupId,
  { allowAllOutbound: true, mutable: true }
);
```